# GAE Development Mode is not working

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine

When i launch my application through:
Debug As -> Web Application

The Development Mode Windows doesn't seem to work because all the options stay gray :

[image: dev mode]

I need to have that working to use the "Reload Web Server" button.

(I guess that the Development Mode will work instead of the console but i'm not sure)

Thank you!

---

**Edits**

So i continued to do some research, i found this : https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/running_and_debugging_2_0

At the end:

> **App Engine-only Applications**
>
> If your application uses App Engine but not GWT, the only indication
>   that the App Engine development server is running will be output in
>   the Console view. App Engine-only launches will not appear in the
>   development mode view. The console output includes the URL of the
>   server, which by default is localhost:8888/. You can change the
>   port number via Eclipse's launch configuration dialog by selecting
>   your Web Application launch and editing the Port value on the Main
>   tab.
>
> If you open a web browser and navigate to the server's address you
>   should see a welcome page with links to any servlets defined by the
>   application.

It's not possible to simply restart the server to load the new changes if you don't use GWT?